# backbone models or collections that never change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Hello sorry for my bad English

I have an application, which the client part is developed with Underscore and Backbone and the server in laravel.
I have several queries to the database that are made in different views, these consultations conducted through laravel but as json step, some have a 13,000 lines and some 45,000 other lines, these queries are cached and works everything perfectly.
I wish I could see only once these consultations and laravel siempe any view data become available.
I have a url router.js that manages and renders the view but in each view when I do need this data:

```
   initialize: function() {
     //This is a collection    
     var os = new OS();
     os.fetch()then(function(){
      //select2 example load drop down
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend Backbone to support promises. I use Q as a promise library but should be similar with any other lib (the example is in es6):

```
import {Collection} from 'backbone';

export default Collection.extend({
    fetch: function (options) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        options = options || {};

        var _success = options && options.success;
        var _error = options && options.error;

        options.success = (models, res, options) => {
          _success && _success(models, res, options);
          deferred.resolve([models, res, options]);
        };

        options.error = (models, res, options) => {
          _error && _error(models, res, options);
          deferred.reject([models, res, options]);
        };

        Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

Then when you define your collection you need to extend from this of course. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Attempts to do so, thanks for your help, I researched about it a few days ago and so far is proved. 
initialize: function(){
        this.MainView = new MainView();
        os.fetch().then(function(){
            window.os = os;
        });
        this.on('finishRendering', function() {
            this.doBootstraping();
        }.bind(this));
    },